# Android: Back stack doesnt work properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I am making an app with a couple of screens and it has to be possible to navigate through the app with the back button.

I am having trouble with one screen, my MainFragment. It doesn't seem recognise the backstack.

The MainFragment is started from the MainActivity here:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment()).addToBackStack("mainFragment")
                .commit();
    }
```

So when the app starts, this fragment is loaded.
From this mainFragment I can navigate to different screens.
I have methods in my mainActivity which I call in my MainFragment to navigate:

```
public void navigateToListCountriesSeen(){
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new listCountriesSeenFragment()).addToBackStack("listSeen")
            .commit();
}

public void navigateToListCountriesToSee(){
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new listCountriesToSeeFragment()).addToBackStack("listToSee")
            .commit();
}
```

But whenever I am in the countriesSeen or CountriesToSee fragments/screens and I press the back button, the app just closes...

How do I solve that?

Comment: Try calling `.add()` instead of `replace()` for the first fragment in the null check, and also use `addToBackStack(null)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addToBackStack()` if you want the navigation to backup on the backspace key.  Here's an example:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ListCountriesSeenFragment listCountriesSeenFragment = new ListCountriesSeenFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, listCountriesSeenFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG_COUNTRIES_SEEN);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: But I am using addToBackStack?
Scroll to the right in my code segments

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't see them.  Which class are you extending for your activity?  I used `getSupportFragmentManager()` in the code above because I'm extending `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: I am extending AppCombatActivity too, is there a difference between getSupportFragmentManager and getFragmentManager?

Comment: Yes, you don't want to mix Support calls with native SDK calls. Try using the `getSupportFragmentManager()` as I use above.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to check the fragment in onBackPressed:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    Fragment currentFragment =getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ll_fragment_container);

    if(currentFragment instanceof CountriesToSee && currentFragment.isVisible()){ //if fragment for info is showing close fragment when back pressed. Otherwise close app
        removeFragment(currentFragment);

    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks awesome!! How do I write the removeFragment method?

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("listSeen");
        if(currentFragment instanceof listCountriesSeenFragment && currentFragment.isVisible()){ //if fragment for info is showing close fragment when back pressed. Otherwise close app
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(currentFragment).commit();

        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }


I tried this, but then there is just nothing? The Mainfragment doesnt appear?

Comment: If you are looking to replace listCountriesSeenFragment with the MainFragment you could just use fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);

Comment: It would be better to get addtobackstack working correctly however. Were you already overriding onbackPressed in the Activity?

Comment: No, do I need to override the onBackPressed method to make addtobackstack properly?

Comment: It's the better method. But the above will probably work as well using the replace method.